# Angular: How to get a array of objects that are nested within the server response?

Tags: angular, observable, angular8

I would like to get data from the server using the following method:

```js
searchProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
  return this.http.get<Product[]>('/lerp-product-product');
}
```

But the data from the server looks like this:

```
{
    "desc": "",
    "auth": 0,
    "success": 1,
    "messages": [],
    "obj": null,
    "arr": [
        {
            "product_uuid": "6d80eb05-451e-4309-b0cf-070a14a8e22e",
            "product_no": "97508175",
            "product_structure": "list",
            "product_origin": "intern",
            "product_type": "part",
            "product_version_extern": "",
            "product_revision_extern": "",
        }
    ],
    "countProducts": 28
}
```

The problem is that the data for the observable is in `arr`. How can you tell `Angular.http` that the data is in `arr` and not directly in the root of the JSON response?

Comment: `.pipe(map(res => res.arr))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach is to use the RXJS [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator to transform the `Observable` HTTP response.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

searchProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
  return this.http.get<Product[]>('/lerp-product-product').pipe(map(
    response => response.arr
  ));
}
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the sevice from your component , you could do access the array arr from the response as follows,

```
this.myService.searchProducts().subscribe(data=> console.log(data.arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in yourservice.ts

```
searchProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
  return this.http.get<Product[]>('/lerp-product-product');
}
```

Call searchProducts method  from yourcomponent.ts

```
 this.yourservice.searchProducts().subscribe(attr => {
     var auth= attr.auth;
var success = attr.success;
like these you will get all the values..

    });
```

Comment: I already had that idea and it works. But you would have to do that wherever you access the data. @Christopher Peisert Answer I have to do only one place (in the service).